# Using seq_along and lapply to process multiple dataframes (CAPM)

Tags: r, lapply, seq

I have 48 dataframes and I wish to calculate a linear regression for each of the stocks in each of the dataframes (the CAPM). Each dataframe contains the same amount of stocks which is around 470, the S&P 500 and has 36 months worth of data. Originally I had one large dataframe but I have successfully managed to split the data into the 48 dataframes (this might not have been the smartest move but it is the way I solved the problem).

When I run the following code, it works fine. Noting that I have hard coded in Block 1.

```
  beta_results <- lapply(symbols, function(x) {
  temp <-  as.data.frame(Block1)
  input <- as.formula(paste("temp$",x, "~ temp$SP500" ))
  capm <- lm(input)
  coefficients(capm)
 })
```

Now rather than change the coding for each of the 48 blocks (ie Block1  to Block2 etc), I attempted the following, which in hindsight is complete rubbish. What I need is a way to increment the i from 1 to 48. I had tried to put all the dataframes in list, but given the way I have regression working I would be processing two lists and that was beyond me.

```
beta_results <- lapply(seq_along(symbols), function(i,x) {
 temp <-  as.data.frame(paste0("Block",i))
 input <- as.formula(paste("temp$",x, "~ temp$SP500" ))
 capm <- lm(input)
coefficients(capm)
})
```

Code for some example dataframes etc are:

```
 symbols <- c("A", "AAPL", "BRKB")
```

Block1 to BlockN would take the form of

```
             A      AAPL  BRKB    SP500
2016-04-29 -0.139  0.111  0.122    0.150 
2016-05-31  0.071  0.095  0.330    0.200 
2016-06-30 -0.042 -0.009  0.230    0.150
2016-07-29  0.090  0.060  0.200    0.100
2016-08-31  0.023  0.013  0.005    0.050  
2016-09-30  0.065  0.088  0.002    0.100
```

Comment: Have you considered using the original single data.frame, then melting so you have date and stock name as ID columns and a single value column. You could then use data.table or dplyr with a by/group to perform linear regression.

Comment: Thanks for this. I had not considered that approach and will have a look at it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider a nested `lapply` where outer loop iterates through a list of dataframes and inner loop through each symbol. The result is a 48-member list, each containing 470 sets of beta coefficents.

Also, as an aside, it is preferred to use lists of many similiarly structured objects especially to run same operations and avoid flooding your global environment (manage 1 list vs 48 dataframes):

```
# LIST OF DATA FRAMES FROM ALL GLOBAL VARIABLES CONTAINING "Block"
dfList <- mget(ls(pattern="Block"))

# NESTED LAPPLY
results_list <- lapply(dfList, function(df) {

  beta_results <- lapply(symbols, function(x) {
     input <- reformulate(quote(SP500), response=x)     
     capm <- lm(input, data=df)
     coefficients(capm)
  })

})
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I appreciate your comment regarding the list over the 48 dataframes. In another cringeworthy move I actual had the single list with the 48 sublists and then split it out into the 48 dataframes and then resembling due to a lack of skill in handling lists. If you are interested I could send you the whole mess......

Comment: I will also say that I think I am paying the price of using the greater minds on Stack Overflow to solve my problems rather than really understanding what is going on.

Comment: Did this solution not work? What errors do you get? Again, use lists of similar structured objects to avoid managing so many others.

Comment: I did have some trouble with the reformulate but managed to work around it.  The approach was ideal, and thanks again for your help

Comment: Great! If solution worked, please accept it to confirm resolution. Also, curious what changes did you make to `reformulate`?

Answer (score 0):

@Parfait's answer is the correct one for OPs question of using lapply to process a list of data frames.

The following example shows how `data.table` can be used to get the `coefficients` of `lm(stock~SP500)` for each stock (using the Block1 example data):

```
library(data.table)
dt <- structure(list(date = c("2016-04-29", "2016-05-31", "2016-06-30", 
"2016-07-29", "2016-08-31", "2016-09-30"), A = c(-0.139, 0.071, 
-0.042, 0.09, 0.023, 0.065), AAPL = c(0.111, 0.095, -0.009, 0.06, 
0.013, 0.088), BRKB = c(0.122, 0.33, 0.23, 0.2, 0.005, 0.002), 
    SP500 = c(0.15, 0.2, 0.15, 0.1, 0.05, 0.1)), .Names = c("date", 
"A", "AAPL", "BRKB", "SP500"), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame")

setDT(dt)
# Convert to long format for easier lm
dt_melt <- melt(dt, id.vars = c("date", "SP500"))
# Extract coefficients by doing lm for each unique variable (i.e. stock)
dt_lm <- dt_melt[, as.list(coefficients(lm(value~SP500))), by = variable]
# Fix column names
setnames(dt_lm, c("stock", "intercept", "slope"))

> dt_lm
   stock   intercept      slope
1:     A  0.05496970 -0.3490909
2:  AAPL  0.01421212  0.3636364
3:  BRKB -0.10751515  2.0454545
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I think this approach will come in very handy on future work